# Trac is unable to read svn repository

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, svn, trac

I've been following [this guide](http://www.subversionary.org/howto/setting-up-a-subversion-server-on-ubuntu-gutsy-gibbon-server) on how to setup svn and trac.

Svn was already running, and is functioning as expected, but trac is not.

When I go to the trac page it says:

```
Warning:  Can't synchronize with the repository
(Couldn't open Subversion repository /home/svn/repos: SubversionException:
("Can't open file '/home/svn/repos/format': Permission denied", 13)).
Look in the Trac log for more information.
```

I've added www-data to the svn group, but that did not work.
I even chowned the svn repository to www-data:www-data, still nothing.
As a last resort I chmodded 777 the entire repository, but that still did not work.

So something else must be causing this, right?

This is my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default file, just in case:

```
<Location /trac/[[:alnum]]+/login">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
  Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /trac>
  SetHandler mod_python
  PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
  PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
  PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /var/www/trac
  PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
</Location>
```

I also tried to add WebDAV access through apache, by adding this to the same file:

```
<Location /svn/repos>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
    Require valid-user
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /home/svn/repos
</Location>
```

But again I'm getting an error:

```
<m:human-readable errcode="13">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem</m:human-readable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `trac-admin project initenv` command congratulated me and said it was successful, it didn't actually create anything. Running it again fixed it.